# Celery-Progress-Bar Not Working in Django

Tags: python, django, progress-bar, celery, django-celery

I am trying to use celery-progress module to show the user the progress of the task, since it takes lot of time to complete the task. However, after following the instructions on https://github.com/czue/celery-progress,I am seeing the following error on the front-end:-

`NoReverseMatch at /netadc/arista/views/getFabListArista/TRCW/
Reverse for 'task_status' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'celery_progress/(?P<task_id>[\\w-]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://x.x.x.x/netadc/arista/views/getFabListArista/TRCW/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Reverse for 'task_status' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'celery_progress/(?P<task_id>[\\w-]+)/$']`

The URL pattern on the front-end `var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id %}";` does not work.
When I change it to `var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' 'task_id' %}";` i do not get the error, but no tasks are running.

Any experts on django/python, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the url mapping of celery_progress to your main urls.py. It's described in the Prerequisites section of the project's README.

Comment: I already have that in there.
url(r'^celery_progress/', include('celery_progress.urls')),

Answer (score 1):

Check here: https://github.com/czue/celery-progress/issues/27

this implies the task ID is blank. The best way to troubleshoot it is to try and figure out why it's blank. It can be because your backend isn't properly configured so the ID is not assigned/returned from the async call, because you're not passing it properly from the view to the template, because you're referencing the wrong variable in the template, etc.

I'd recommend you get to the bottom of why the ID is blank and that should hopefully lead you to the appropriate solution.